# Netbeans Error : Schema doesnt exist

Tags: java, sql, xml, jsp, netbeans

So i am trying to access my underlying database in java application in netbeans through a simple jsp page :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<sql:query var="rslt" dataSource="jdbc/cart">
   select isbn, title, quantity, price from dbsample.books
</sql:query>
<html>
<head>
     <title>JDBC Connection Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Available books:</h1>
    <c:forEach var="book" items="${rslt.rows}">
        <b>Isbn:</b> ${book.isbn}<br/>
        <b>Title:</b> ${book.title}<br/>
        <b>Price:</b> $${book.price}<br/>
        <b>In stock:</b> ${book.quantity}<br/>
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>
 </body>
</html>
```

but i am getting this error :

> select isbn, title, quantity, price from dbsample.books : Schema 'DBSAMPLE' does not exist

This is the stack trace:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: 
>       select isbn, title, quantity, price from dbsample.books
>   : Schema 'DBSAMPLE' does not exist
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:951)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:886)
>       at org.apache.jsp.testPage_jsp._jspService(testPage_jsp.java:80)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:630)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'DBSAMPLE' does not exist
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:586)
>       at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
>       at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
>       at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:992)
>       at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:173)
>       at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doEndTag(QueryTagSupport.java:255)
>       at org.apache.jsp.testPage_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_query_0(testPage_jsp.java:119)
>       at org.apache.jsp.testPage_jsp._jspService(testPage_jsp.java:60)
>       ... 47 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Schema 'DBSAMPLE' does not exist
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
>       ... 56 more

Now i have checked my web.xml. the deployment descriptor is correct to the best of my knowledge. I have checked my datasource it seems correct to according to my persistance.xml I pinged the database pool and it was successful too. My schema is named dbsample and has a table named books.

So i cant figure out why it is saying to my DBSAMPLE doesnt exist. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT # 1 when executing the sql command in database it works totally fine.
[image]

Comment: Could you execute the same sql sentence in your database and check you don't have the same error

Comment: so i executed it in my database and it works totally fine.

Comment: then I think the reason is the datasource jdbc/cart is connect to another database that don't has this schema, you could check the url y  databasename properties of your datasource and check if it point to the correct database.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I think I'm running the same example you are and getting the same problem

Comment: @peeskillet...it usually coonection problem.. dont remember exactly how i solved it.. but basically its hit and trail.. check connection pool and resources.. persistance unit etc...
hopefully will work..

Answer (score 3):

Although I might be a little late to answer this, but I came across the same problem and solved it.

The problem was that I did not set the JDBC resource in my `persistnece.xml`. I added this to my `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<jta-data-source>jdbc/resourcename</jta-data-source>
```

Change `jdbc/resourcename` to your JDBC resource!

Comment: Thanks though it is a little late. I hope it helps someone down the road :)